# jQuery UI Sortable & draggable helper

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I try to make draggable &sortable content with jQuery UI when i use:

`helper:clone` property

it's work perfectly, but i don't want to clone elements. 
I want move them and when i use default helper then elements are not sortable.

Elements are on the stack in one place, instead of move other elements to make empty place form dragged element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/veb2w95p/ uncomment helper:clone to see difference

Comment: what you need is drag and drop items from category 2 to category 1 and vice versa?

Comment: yes and i can have more than two categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See those Html and script below

This works for 2 categories

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="category" data-category="1">
            <div class="noteCategory">
                <h3>Cat 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="categorycontent1" class="categoryContent">
                <div class="note cnote" data-id="2" data-category="1">
                    <span class="noteDate">
                        <span class="date">
                            2015-01-01
                        </span>
                        <span class="hour">
                            12:12
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="remove"></a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="noteText">
                        note Text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="note cnote" data-id="2" data-category="1">
                    <span class="noteDate">
                        <span class="date">
                            2015-01-02
                        </span>
                        <span class="hour">
                            12:12
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="remove"></a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="noteText">
                        note Text 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="category" data-category="2">
            <div class="noteCategory">
                <h3>Cat 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="categorycontent2" class="categoryContent">
                <div class="note cnote" data-id="5" data-category="2">
                    <span class="noteDate">
                        <span class="date">
                            2015-01-04
                        </span>
                        <span class="hour">
                            12:12
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="remove"></a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="noteText">
                        note Text 22
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="note cnote" data-id="8" data-category="2">
                    <span class="noteDate">
                        <span class="date">
                            2015-01-06
                        </span>
                        <span class="hour">
                            12:12
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="remove"></a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="noteText">
                        note Text 23
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#categorycontent1, #categorycontent2").sortable({
                connectWith: ".categoryContent"
            }).disableSelection();

        });

    </script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: that's work i done it for many categories and works good thanks